A shortcoming with our existing resources question
I closed this question just now https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/introduction-to-pinyin?noredirect=1 but it brought something to my attention. Our resources question Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese has things categorized by type of media which is not the issue, but what about when people want to find resources for a particular issue.
The closed question is not necessarily a bad one that we couldn't provide an answer to, but the answer (I feel) doesn't quite fit in with the way our current resources question is categorized. 
In the answer for that question some guy provided a great resource this one which would be helpful to someone wanting to learn pinyin.
I also don't want to screw up the formatting and grouping of the current resources question, so does anyone have any suggestions?

Is it worthwhile to provide resources for these sorts of issues?
Should we have another question categorized differently?
How can we structure this new question and what should we call it?

Some examples I can think of:

Resources to learn writing
Resources to learn pronunciation
Resources to learn tones and pinyin

etc.

I have an idea: just add another answer to that resources question called Basics or something of that sort, and there you can put introductions, basic information for those who are just approaching the language and want to know about it for the first time. Things about how the language works, etc... you get the idea. Including the Pinyin thing, for example.
Then you can add that to the index in the question. Even above all the other items since it's something introductory.

Couple of concerns, would this become too large over time and can it be easily found via search?

@xiaohouzi79 1) No because we aim to make it comprehensive (list what is necessary, not everything). 2) I think so.
